# curl runs from command line, but not in ruby script

Tags: ruby, windows, curl

The following command (and variations of it) run okay in terminal in mac, run okay in a ruby program executed on a mac, run okay directly in the windows command prompt, but fail with a parsing error when I try to run it inside of a ruby file on windows.

```
curl -u"user:pwd" -d"{\"name\":\"new_repo_beepo\"}" https://api.github.com/user/repos --insecure
```

I've tried executing it with backticks, %x() and system.  I've also tried substitution of strings and json'ing pieces of it, without any luck.  From what I can determine, the failure point is in the `-d"{\"name\":\"repo_name\"}"` section, but that's only from trying the command without it.  Regardless, in each variation of the command on windows in ruby, I get a JSON parsing error.

Comment: Possibly a parsing/quoting problem with the shell mechanism used by ruby to run the command on windows.  Have you tried the tokenized form of `system`, eg: `system('curl','-u"user:pwd"', '-d...', ...)`? On posix that will send the arg vector as specified directly to the exec'ed program without letting the shell get in the way.

Comment: Why curl anyway?  In ruby you can use Net::HTTP to do this directly.

Comment: Thanks, dbenhur -- I will give the tokenized form a shot this afternoon.  As for your other question, our systems run jruby and the native extensions seem to be a problem for Net:HTTP, curb, and the others I found.

Comment: @dbenhur: The tokenized version worked perfectly!  Thanks a lot!

Comment: @dbenhur: by the way, if you want to submit that same suggestion as an answer I will choose it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems likely this is a parsing/quoting problem with the shell mechanism used by ruby to run the command on windows. Have you tried the tokenized form of system, eg:

```
system('curl', '-u"user:pwd"', '-d"{"name":"new_repo_beepo"}"', 'https://api.github.com/user/repos', '--insecure')
```

On posix that will send the arg vector as specified directly to the exec'ed program without letting the shell get in the way; probably the same semantics hold for windows.

You shouldn't need to exec curl to do this as ruby has stdlib Net::HTTP. In comments you mentioned that you've had problems with this module under jruby, but we have jruby services here exercising http[s] requests just fine, so you might try posting a question addressing the specific problems you have with jruby and native http client libs.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried using [rest-client](https://github.com/archiloque/rest-client)?

It is a gem and works quite nice. It is probably better than using `system()`or `%x()` and it is definitely more secure (You can inject malicious bash commands on `system()` so it needs to be used carefully).

It is quite simple to use. Just install the gem and require it one your ruby file.

NOTE: If using Rails just add it to your Gemfile(No need to require it on each file).

```
require 'rest_client'

RestClient.get 'https://api.github.com/user/repos', {params: {id: 50, foo: 'bar'}}
```

You can also use some params for `--insecure` ssl.